# Findind the parameter that makes two matrices similar

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find the parameter **h** which will make Matrix A similar to Matrix B.

Matrix A
\begin{bmatrix}3&2&0\\h&1&5\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Matrix B
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}

There are a lot of methods to solve this, I chose to find Matrix A Eigenvalues which must be equal to the Matrix B Eigenvalues.

The next step then is to find Matrix A Eigenvalues using the Characteristic polynomial of Matrix A.

\begin{vmatrix}3-λ&2&0\\h&1-λ&5\\0&0&1-λ\end{vmatrix}

I'll use Sarrus rule to find its determinant which in the end will result:

$$(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-2h+2h\lambda=0$$

$$(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-2h(1-\lambda)=0$$

$$(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda)^2-2h(1-\lambda)=0$$
$$(1-\lambda)[(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-2h]$$

I get stuck at this point, I tried to expand the equation but I don't think that's the best way to solve this.

$$ [(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-2h]=0$$

What I need to do is factor this part of the equation but I don't know where I should start.

Comment: Look at that last equation. What does $h$ need to be in order for $3$ to be an eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: In order to get $3$ as an eigenvalue of $A$ there should be no $h$ in that equation, so the in the end you would get just $$(1-\lambda)^2(3-\lambda)$$

Comment: And $h$ would therefore be ... ?

Comment: $h$ should be $0$, but I didn't get why $λ$ should be $3$ in that case. Is it because we already know that Matrix B has $3$, $1$ and $1$ as eigenvaues?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don Antonio's answer is basically the best way in which you can start. Indeed having identical determinant and trace is a necessary condition but it's not sufficient. Lots of matrices can be "fake similar" in this way.

You need identical eigenvalues. From the $B$ matrix you immediately see its eigenvalues are $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = 3$ (the first one is doubled).

So, when you come to solve the characteristic polynomial for matrix $A$ you expect to have the same.

Your equation is

$$(1-\lambda)[(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda) - 2h] = 0$$

You can immediately see $\lambda = 1$ is one of them. But you now need another one of that and $\lambda = 3$.

By simply looking at the equation, you find out that the condition must be $h = 0$, in that way the equation gets rid of the $2h$ term, nad you indeed get what you want.

In case you "can't notice it", just develop the equation, making it identical to what you need:

$$(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda) - 2h = (3-\lambda)(1 - \lambda)$$

Hence necessarily $h = 0$.

Finally, if you really want the whole steps, you can expand your equation:

$$\lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 3 - 2h = 0$$

Finding

$$\lambda_{1,\ 2} = \frac{4\pm\sqrt{16 - 4(3-2h)}}{2} = \frac{4\pm2\sqrt{4 - (3-2h)}}{2} = 2\pm \sqrt{1 + 2h}$$

Hence

$$\lambda_1 = 2 + \sqrt{1 + 2h}$$

Which is $3$ iff $h = 0$

And

$$\lambda_2 = 2 - \sqrt{1 + 2h}$$

Which is $1$ iff $h = 0$

So you get, with a clear proof, that $h = 0$.

Comment: Ok, that's clear now. Just one more question. Matrix B eigenvalues are $3$, $1$ and $1$. So in the end with Matrix A we must get the same. We checked for $3$ which gives $h=0$ but what about the second $\lambda = 1$ ? Couldn't we check for that in the latest equation instead of looking at $3$?

Comment: Also "identical eigenvalues" don't **necessarily** give similarity, as this very example proves: both matrices have $\;1,1,3\;$ as eigenvalues ( after we deduce $\;h=0\;$ with the determinant of $\;A\;$) and yet they *aren't* similar...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes sorry, I meant that we need ALL the three conditions :D

Comment: @FourierTransform Perhaps I missed something, sorry: **what** "three conditions"?

Comment: @DonAntonio The conditions by which two matrices are similar: they share eigenvalues, determinant and trace (and rank). Also we can go for the algebraic definition: "two matrices that represent an endomorphism with respect to different basis of a given vector space are necessarily similar".

Comment: @DonAntonio Or we can as usual find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = D$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues as elements, and $A$ is our matrix. Et cetera.

Comment: @FourierTransform It is **not** enough that two matrices have the same determinant, trace and exactly the same eigenvalues for them to be similar, and this question's matrices are an example of that! Both $\;A,B\;$ have trace $\;5\;$ , determinant $\;3\;$ and their eigenvalues are $\;1,1,3\;$ ...and **still** they are **not** similar. This is what I was thinking before and I'm afraid the OP, and also you, didn't know this. The **actual** definition of *similar matrices* is what you wrote in your second part: both matrices represent the same linear operator wrt different basis. That is true.

Comment: @DonAntonio mm I always read that the first condition is required too! I mean, it's necessary but not sufficient as you said. But it's the starting point to make things easy as you did! Probably I shall have developed the answer with finding the $P$ matrix?

Comment: @FourierTransform Your last line seems to indicate that $\;h=0\;$ is "the solution" to the OP problem, and thus with $\;h=0\;$ the matrices are similar, and this is not **so**: either the OP didn't read/understand, he still seems to believe that. The *solution* is that $\;A\,,\,\,B\;$ are **not similar** no matter what $\;h\;$ is, as showed in my answer...unless, of course, I made some mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Why not try *first* the easy things? The trace and determinant must be equal. The former is, but for the latter we have:

$$\det B=3\;,\;\;\det A=3-2h\implies h=0$$

is a necessary condition for similarity...but perhaps not sufficient. Substitute $\;h=0\;$ and now go with eigenvalues or whatever.

**Added as further help (because the comments make it clear this is necessary)**: The characteristic polynomial of the first matrix is (assuming already $\;h=0\;$)

$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-3&\!-2&0\\0&x-1&\!-5\\0&0&x-1\end{vmatrix}=(x-1)^2(x-3)$$

As $\;A\;$ must be diagonal, it is enough to check whether the eigenspace of $\;\lambda=1\;$ is of dimension two:

$$\lambda=1:\;\;\begin{cases}-2x-2y=0\\-5z=0\\\end{cases}\;\;\implies x=-y,\,z=0$$

and we thus get $\;\dim V_1=1\implies A\;$ isn't diagonalizable and thus $\;A\;$ cannot be similar to $\;B\;$ no matter what.

Comment: Your first two steps makes things a lot easier, but as Fourier Trasnform said those two don't make a Matrix similar to another, that's why I went directly for the eigenvalues. However it is ok if you find $h$ though the determinant and the trace and then you check if you get real and distict eigenvalues (that must be equal to those of Matrix B) with $h$ set to $0$. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @matt95 From the beginning I wrote that the conditions are necessary *but not sufficient*: you can read there. Also having the same eigenvalues is **not** a sufficient condition, only necessary...as this very example proves! This particular problem becomes much easier after the trace and determinant are checked and $\;h=0\;$ is deduced, and then you check eigenvalues **and also** their geometric multiplicity.